# Magento_Integration schema: current version - 2.2.0, required version - 2.0.1

Tags: database, upgrade, magento2.1.5

Using 2.1.5, I'm getting an error message saying:

```
"Magento_Integration schema: current version - 2.2.0, required version - 2.0.1"
```

I've `tried setup:update` and `setup:db-data:upgrade`.

The site was installed via cPanel/installation version 2.0.7 and has been upgraded several times.

The only thing that brings the site back online is if I edit the Magento_Integration entry of the setup_module table which I would think is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `setup_module` table into the database.

You should see something similar to this:

[image]

In order to fix it, set the values manually to 2.0.1 for both `schema` and `data` and then try to upgrade again with the following:

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Then flush cache:

`bin/magento cache:flush`

It looks like for some reason the upgrade did not work or did not finish but Magento update `setup_module` table.

By setting those values manually and running the upgrade afterwards you are forcing the upgrade one more time.

You can actually see what this particular upgrade does in:

```
// \Magento\Integration\Setup\UpgradeData::upgrade()

public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.2.0', '<')) {
            $this->removeRevokedTokens($setup);
            $this->removeTokensFromInactiveAdmins($setup);
            $this->removeTokensFromInactiveCustomers($setup);
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
```

As you can see, all it does it to ***remove revoked and inactive tokens.***

Comment: That is what I see. But I still get an error after running setup:upgrade and cache:flush. The error goes away if I change both to 2.0.1 but I'm guessing that's not a good idea.

Comment: Could you try setting both values to 2.0.1 manually, and then executing  `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: That works. But will I be causing a problem by doing that? Something set the values to 2.2.0.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some more details.